# How to make preloader image load first

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to make a preloder page.

The problem is that my preloader image is a little bit heavy
so it takes some time until it loads.
This is happens because all the files are loaded simultaneously, so it takes time until it fully loaded.

I want to configure that the the preloader image is loaded first and only when it finishes, then browser will load the all other files.

How can I set that nothing loads until this image loads completely?

This is the code im using:

Jquery:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     $(window).on('load', function () {
     $('#loading').hide();
  });
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#loading {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: fixed;
   display: block;
   opacity: 1;
   background-color: #fff;
   z-index: 99;
   text-align: center;
}

#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="loading">
<img id="loading-image" src="preloader.gif" alt="Loading..." /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Move your loading element to the top of the page.

Comment: You can load all scripts after `body`

Comment: The scripts are not the problem. the media is the larger content

Comment: the loading element is on the top of the body. but still it loads simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Your static files such as javascripts and styles should load first but you can post pond loading other images until your preloader image has finished loading. If you want so, instead of filling `src` attribute of `img`s, fill a new attribute such as `data-src` and leave `src` attribute empty. Then use following code to load images after your preloader has finished loading.

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('img').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

PS: An alternative solution could be using [lazyload](https://github.com/verlok/lazyload) to overcome this problem.

Comment: hey! I tried using your method but the thing is that it caused that the preloader page immidiately disappeared and the objects are being loaded regularly. The point is that I dont want it to load the images after the loading div is hidden. i want it to stiil be on when it all loads (that's all the purpose of preloader...) but i want that the preloader image will be loaded first.

Comment: give this plugin [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) a try

Answer (score 0):

Now this is may seem like a `cool` way to do things but technically speaking, you are just making your users wait till you image loads up and then adding all the images. However this is how you would do this. Move all the image sources(their urls) from the src attribute to data-src attribute. You can do this with script files as well. Then do this.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var files = $("[data-src]");
    $.each(files, function(index, element){
        //This is just the check for the last file
        if(index === files.length){
            $(element).on("load error", function(){
                $('#loading').hide();            
            });
        }
        $(element).attr("src", $(element).data("src"));
    });
  });
</script>
```